# Returning const reference from function

Tags: c++

I want my function to return an array of objects. But i want some restriction on returned reference so that returned value/reference is not modified by caller.

Eg

```
class A
{
    B **arrB;

    public :
        A() 
        {
            initialize arrB 
        }
        B** getB()
        {
           return arrB;
        }
}
```

In above code, array returned by getB() function, should not be modified.
Can someone suggest best way to do this ?
Can "const" help?

Comment: Any reason you're not just returning a `vector`?

Comment: `const` can help but if the user casts the pointer to a non-const pointer he can modify the vector ... But from what I know `const` is the only way to do it

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason not to, use standard containers. Maybe you need a vector of vectors, maybe you need a flat vector.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need it?

Comment: @IulianŞerbănoiu But if the user wants to break the abstraction, he can do it anyway. For example, he can cast the class itself to another class with the same members, but public. It's 100% undefined behaviour, but it might work.

Comment: @Brendan: I can return vector, but it will still require some memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will help. But then you will get an error about illegal conversion from `B **` to `const B **`, but that is the reason for `const_cast`:

```
const B** getB() const
{
    return const_cast<const B**>(arrB);
}
```

Note that I added an extra `const` qualifier after the function declaration. This tells the compiler that the function does not modify anything in the class.

Comment: Thanks..this seems to be what i am looking for. Will try this out.

Answer (score 4):

this should do it:

```
const B * const * getB() const { return arrB; }
```

EDIT: added const since member function doesn't modify contents.

Answer (score 1):

`const` doesn't really help. The compiler may raise some warnings/errors when you try to modify the array, but you can always cast to a non-`const` pointer and modify it.
`const` is more a hint to the user of the class: the pointer I'm giving you you is read-only; modify it at your peril!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the possible way I see is to return new array copied from the private one (containing copies of original object instances). If you want to be sure the private member of the class is not changed you then need not to care about what the code which takes the copy of arrB pointer will do with it. But of course there are disadvantages like more memory usage and that the consumer has to delete obtained array.